# android save image to the gallery

Tags: android, bitmap

why i can't save the Drawing Cache in the gallery

```
else if(view.getId()==R.id.save_btn){
        //save drawing
        AlertDialog.Builder saveDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

        saveDialog.setTitle("Save drawing");

        saveDialog.setMessage("Save drawing to device Gallery?");

        saveDialog.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
```

The save path

```
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which){
                //save drawing
                drawView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
                String imgSaved = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(
                        getContentResolver(), drawView.getDrawingCache(),
                        UUID.randomUUID().toString()+".png", "drawing");
```

if the image saved

```
                if(imgSaved!=null){
                    Toast savedToast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
                        "Drawing saved to Gallery!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    savedToast.show();
                }
```